# Counter Loop - Java

Tags: java

Edit:  I have found a way to work with CompareTo to help with this problem, but for some reason I cannot get the count down to work.

It's a negative number that needs to get more negative to meet the requirements, but I am missing something here.  When I execute the down section it closes the program.  So to me this means that I have something messed up and the program isnt seeing the problem and closing.

We are supposed to:

> Ask the user for an integer then ask the user if he/she wants to count
>   up or down. Display a table of numbers where the first column contains
>   the counter, the second column contains the counter plus 10, and the
>   third column contains the counter plus 100. Make it so each number
>   takes up 5 spaces total.
>
> If counting up, the first column should contain numbers 1 through the
>   user input; If counting down, the first column should contain numbers
>   -1 through the the negative of the user input;
>
> Do user input validation on the word "up" and "down". Allow for any
>   case.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ps1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Comparision string already declared
    String up = "up";
    String down = "down";

    //initialize the counters sum
    int sum = 0;

    //ask the user for a number
    System.out.println("Enter an ending value");
    int num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Count up or down?");
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();

    while (input.equalsIgnoreCase(up) || input.equalsIgnoreCase(down)) {
        System.out.println("Count up or down?");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
    }

    if (input.compareToIgnoreCase(up) == 0) {
        if (num1 >= 0)
    for (int c = 1; c <= num1; c++) {
            sum = sum + c;
            System.out.printf("%5d%5d%5d\n", c, c + 10, c + 100);
            else 
                System.out.println("Up numbers must be positive");

    if (input.compareToIgnoreCase(down) == 0) {
            for (int c1 = -1; c1 <= num1; c1--) {
                sum = sum + c1;
                System.out.printf("%5d%5d%5d\n", c1, c1 + 10, c1 + 100);

            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: else ( int counter1 = -1;
    counter1 >= num1;
    counter1--){
        sum = sum + counter1;
    }  ?!!!!!

Comment: OP: it might be useful to actually add the print statements, and include a sample output that shows the trouble you are having.  Right now your question is a little broad.

Comment: This is why code formatting is important. If you had formatted your code correctly, you'd see immediately that the else block was *nested inside* of the if block and would never execute. Don't take code formatting for granted.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are allowing user to enter a positive `num1` and count down using `for (int counter1 = -1; counter1 >= num1; counter1--)`. This makes no sense as `counter1 >= num1` resolves to `-1 >= 1` which is never true. When direction is down the number must be negative and when direction is up the number must be positive.
2. You might need to loop until user provides a valid direction. Currently you go down for any input that is not `up`. A possible solution would be to:

   ```
   String input;
   do {
     input = keyboard.nextLine();
   } while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("up") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("down"));
   ```
3. Please use shorter variable names. `counter1` is scoped just to the `for` loop block so call it `i`. It's easier to read.
4. Whichever editor you are using configure auto formatting :)

Comment: The OPs instructions say `numbers -1 through the the negative of the user input`  num1 must be negative in the case of down input.  I think you were assuming num1 was positive.

Comment: @markspace you are right, I corrected my answer. Thank you.

Comment: When i enter 90 and I want the counting loop to go from -1 to -90 do It does not work the same as it does for a positive number.  I am lost then in how to get it to go negative?

Answer (score 2):

I see you have figured out core logic. BTW, your code will not compile, there is a syntax error.

Your code would look like this:
    print(a   a+10   a+100)

I know that it's not valid syntax but you would be able to figure out the correct way to write the code.

To print data properly, you will need following:
https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples

I would recommend visualizing the output first. In your case, it would look like following: (_are spaces)

```
 Enter an ending value: 2
 Direction: Up
 ____1___11__101
 ____2___12__102
```

Also, think about error cases. What will happen in following:

```
 Enter an ending value: -10
 Direction: Up
 Error: Improper data
```

Comment: The OP should probably ask their instructor for clarification.  They might be expected to validate the data as you point out.

Comment: I am just throwing a hint. It might give OP an extra point and curiosity to explore error cases.

Comment: This is what I meant by my brain wasnt working properly yesterday.  I see that I need to have a solution to either up or down case.  with also an error for not defining one or the other.  I could loop the entry of up or down that way if something else is entered it would repeat itself.

Comment: There you go. I will say you are going on the right track. Keep it up.

Comment: Edited the original post with working code now I have an error I am not seeing in the down section.

Comment: Does it need to be an else if statement?

Comment: No, do not use if else. Think what will happen if you pass up123. You should jot down all the possible inputs which can be: up, down, up123, down_up.

Comment: the loop is repeating for the down section so i messed up something with the compareto for down.... hmm

Comment: oh and I see what you mean there is a logic error starting from a negative number with the up command because it counts from 1 + to number..  I could easily do a check to make sure the number is > 0 with an if statement but for the problem set it doesnt ask for that check to be implemented.

Comment: But logically, it should let the user know that the input was incorrect if the user supplies incorrect input.

Comment: edited that but the else attached to the check to see if its a positive number shows improper format?   Can i attach a secondary command to a loop like this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166907/discussion-between-jr-ibkr-and-sean-gowing).